# Convert Wordpress default grid to carousel

Tags: gallery

I add image grid in post in wordpress. But How can I convert this default wordpress gallery to carousel gallery?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't edit the parent theme to add functionality instead use child theme.
To convert default wordpress gallery to your custom image gallery ( in your case carousel ), you can use jQuery.